# Finding a parameter is set in an INI file with ant

Tags: ant

I have a configuration file, call it "config.ini", and I have something like this:

```
somevar1=11111
somevar2=11111
password=
somevar4=11111
```

How can I make in Ant, to know if the password paramenter has been set (to anything) for my build script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### build.xml

```
<project name="ant-length-of-property" default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <condition property="password.set" else="false">
            <and>
                <isset property="password"/>
                <length string="${password}" when="greater" length="0"/>
            </and>
        </condition>

        <echo>password.set: ${password.set}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

### Output of command: ant -Dpassword=myPassw0rd

```
run:
     [echo] password.set: true
```

### Output of command: ant -Dpassword=

```
run:
     [echo] password.set: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `property` task:

```
<property file="config.ini"/>

<condition property="password.set" else="false">
  <isset property="passowrd"/>
</condition>
```